# Get binary data with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-web-api, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to test JSON vs binary JSON performance on different approaches.
I'm doing a really simple XMLHttpRequest to get the binary data:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", uri, true);
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";
```

I'm also get a regular JSON data with a different request.

The thing I don't understand is that when I look in the network tab on Chrome DevTools or on Fiddler I get the same size of data in both the binary JSON and the regular JSON.

My server side is ASP.NET Web Api 2. 
The formatter that I'm using on the server is: ProtoBufFormatter

I really want to understand the case here and what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: what is binary json? if it's just uft json shipped via arraybuffer, you'de be better off with just a string. if you have real binary data (like an image file, not json), then shipping an arraybuffer could save the escaping overhead of JSON's strings. it's also usually easier to use a Blob() than an array buffer...

Comment: @dandavis it's an array of data. not something like image.

Comment: when you say `same size of data`, do you mean down to the byte? or is it a case of same number of kBytes? I'd look at the actual data being sent by the server, if it's different in each case and the size is the same, that's called a coincidence

Comment: @JaromandaX down to the byte